# Como plotar o gráfico de uma equação complexa em latex?

Tags: latex, plot

Preciso criar gráficos standard maps (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_map). Como posso implementar um gráfico como este abaixo em latex?

[image: Gráfico standard map[1]]]

Comment: Olá. Bem vindo ao SOPT. A sua dúvida está um pouco ampla e, portanto, difícil de ser respondida (a não ser que alguém te desse o código literalmente pronto, e esse não é o objetivo deste site). Você já tentou algo, tem algum código de base? Você consegue ao menos explicar o que é esse gráfico ou como ele é construído? Há várias formas de fazer gráficos/desenhos em LaTeX, sendo a mais famosa o uso do pacote [Tikz](http://cremeronline.com/LaTeX/minimaltikz.pdf). Mas é difícil sugerir um exemplo sem saber como esse gráfico funciona (qual é a origem dos dados, o que representa, etc).

Comment: Pode te ajudar este site com exemplos diversos de gráficos em Tikz (no link, exemplos matemáticos, mas no site há outros tipos de exemplos): http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/area/mathematics/